# Is it guaranteed that template template parameter invoke user provided deduction guides

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Consider an example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template <template <class> class TT> //#1
struct Foo {
   static void foo() {
      static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(TT("abc")), TT<std::string>>);
   }
};

template <class T>
struct Bar {
    Bar(T) {}
};

template <class T>
Bar(T) -> Bar<std::string>; //#2

int main() {
    Foo<Bar>::foo();
}
```

[[clang]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dsdwHaes8YwCmAMm) as well as [[gcc]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gQyQtF0WswZdUe5u) both seem to use user provided deduction guides (#2) when deducing the template parameter of template template parameter (#1). Is it a standard compliant feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is standard compliant.

According to [[dcl.type.simple]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#simple-2):

> A *type-specifier* of the form `typename`<sub>opt</sub> *nested-name-specifier*<sub>opt</sub> *template-name* is a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]). The *template-name* shall name a class template that is not an injected-class-name.

And [[temp.param]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#3):

> A *type-parameter* whose identifier does not follow an ellipsis defines its identifier to be a *typedef-name* (if declared without `template`) or *template-name* (if declared with `template`) in the scope of the template declaration.

`TT` is a type-parameter declared with `template`, which makes it a *template-name* and hence a placeholder for a deduced class type. All the usual rules apply just fine.

Comment: I actually expected that answer, but if it happened to be wrong.. well then I'll take it back ;)

Comment: as a side little question: you think the automatic deduction guides shouldn't be applied either?

Comment: @W.F. Okay, I completely flipped the answer :)

Comment: Nice finding! See - still doesn't have to take it back! :)